# Fabric.api import error from fabric.exceptions

Tags: python, pip, fabric

So I tryd to import from fabric.api **execute**

like that:

```
from fabric.api import execute
```

but I always get this ImportError: **cannot import name 'NetworkError' from 'fabric.exceptions'**

The only other import from fabric im using is:
**from fabric import Connection, task**

and there is no problem only on the execute import I get this error.

installiert habe ich:

- fabric Version: 3.0.1
- fabric3 Version: 1.14.post1

but for some reason its nut finding the execute import

my python version is 3.11

the problem appears when Im installing more then just fabric3 then I get this error but the problem is that when Im only using fabric3 the connection import dosent work